# Vue.js select multiple value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to set value to select with multiple=true within vue.js. When I'm setting v-model, everything is ok

```
<select v-model="selected" multiple style="width: 50px;">
```

but when I'm setting v-bind:value no value is selected in select tag

```
<select v-bind:value="selected" multiple style="width: 50px;">
```

[Example Code](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfcujs16/)

How can I set read-only value to select?

Update: I'm using this in component, so v-model can't be used, I have to use v-bind:value + v-on:change pair. Change function already done and works like a charm, so no question regarding it.

Comment: what's wrong with v-model? what's your intention to use value?

Comment: I need value to be read-only, not two-way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but it may be an option:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example-6',
  data: {
    selected: ['A', 'B'],
    options: ['A', 'B', 'C']
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example-6" class="demo">
  <select multiple style="width: 50px;">
     <option v-for="option in options" :selected="selected.indexOf (option) != -1">{{option}}</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I searched for some hours to find a solution to forward the value and event.

I started my research in reading source code and I find some interesting things. When you use `v-model`, vue.js generates [a piece of code at runtime](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ec78fc8b6d03e59da669be1adf4b4b5abf670a34/packages/vue-template-compiler/build.js#L3479). These code retreat the event to simplify the assignement.

This save my life for the case when the select is not multiple, but the problem stayed. I suppose there is something similar for the binding of attribute value, but I didn't find it. If someone have it, I'm interested to have the source.

Finally I found a simple solution. The aim is just forwarding the v-model interactions of select (bind value and input event). I create a component with:

- computed property `model` with a getter and setter.
- a `prop` value.

With these, we take advantages of the generated piece of code with the setter, because the value passed is the refined value. The getter don't need to be more complex.

```js
{
  props: ["value"],
  computed: {
    model: {
      get: () => {
        // value is a prop of the component
        return this.value;
      },

      set: (valueSelect) => {
        this.$emit("input", valueSelect);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The template :

```html
<template>
  <select v-model="model">
    <slot></slot>
  </select>
</template>
```

I hope this help.

Sorry for the syntax, but I'm writing component in Typescript so it is really different. I write here in typescript and sfc syntax.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";
import { Prop, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class SelectComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop({
    required: true
  })
  private value: any[] | any;

  @Prop({
    default: false
  })
  private multiple: boolean;

  private get model() {
    return this.value;
  }

  private set model(value) {
    this.$emit("input", value);
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <select v-model="model" :multiple="multiple">
    <slot></slot>
  </select>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do:

```
<div id="example-6" class="demo">
  <select multiple disabled v-model="selected" style="width: 50px;">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

Your [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfcujs16/6/).

`v-model` actually uses `v-bind` behind the scenes. If you only use `v-bind` you'll be missing the input event handling and no change to the input will be propagated to the state.

**Update:**

Using `v-bind:value`, it's only possible to select one option:

```
v-bind:value="selected[0]" // in the select tag
```

And you may also do like:

```
<div id="example-6" class="demo">
  <select multiple disabled style="width: 50px;">
    <option :selected="selected[0]">A</option>
    <option :selected="selected[1]">B</option>
    <option :selected="selected[2]">C</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfcujs16/12/)

Here's a more elegant way for this:

```
<div id="example-6" class="demo">
  <select multiple disabled style="width: 50px;">
    <option v-for="(option, index) in options" :selected="selected[index]">
    {{ option }}
  </option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfcujs16/13/)

Comment: exactly, but via value, not via options.

Comment: I'm using this in component, so v-model can't be used, I have to use v-bind:value + v-on:change pair. v-on:change is already implemented.

Comment: the updated answer has  all it can be done. hope this helps.